# Differences between files: Output unexpected when there are duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find differences between my data files.

File1.txt: Orange, orange, apple, pear

File2.txt: pear, Pear, Kiwi

Output.txt:

```
-Orange
-Orange
-apple
-pear
+pear
+Pear
+Kiwi
```

In this case lowercase "pear" is the only common fruit between my files and thus the output shows both +pear and -pear. But this is not extremely helpful because I want to use this code for really long gene lists. Is there some way to further filter the common fruit and display them for example without a "+" or "-" the output.txt. As this is not very helpful to have to go through what has + and  - in a very big list  full of duplicates.

this is my code:

```
import difflib

with open('/Users/.../file1.txt') as file_1:file_1_text = file_1.readlines()
with open('/Users/.../file2.txt') as file_2:file_2_text = file_2.readlines()

mfile = open('output.txt', 'w')    

for line in difflib.unified_diff(file_1_text, file_2_text,fromfile='file1.txt',tofile='/Users/.../file2.txt', lineterm=''):    
        mfile.write("%s\n" % line)    
        print(line)
```

Comment: Why does it say `-Orange` twice?

Comment: It is just an  example when I first run my code to see how it behaves when there are duplicates within the same file.